# Connection to remote oracle db from c# code

Tags: database, oracle, connection-string, plsqldeveloper

I  need to connect to remote oracle db from c# code. Client has a PL/SQL Developer installed and working, it should help me find out settings for my custom application.

**The question is**: How can I get connection string from PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: A very important question is what version of .NET framework are you using? Prior to 4.0, you could use `System.Data.OracleClient`, but now you have to go with a third party provider. I tend to use ODP.NET by Oracle for projects of .NET framework 4.0 or greater.

Comment: it doesn't matter) I can use ODP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.connectionstrings.com is a great resource to look up connection strings between various languages and databases. http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle, more specifically, has the connection string information you're looking for.

Comment: I need a certain string not a general one.

Comment: `Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=YOUR_HOST_ADDRESS)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME)));User Id=YOUR_USER_NAME;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD;"`


This is what I use with ODP.NET to connect to PlSQL in .NET 4.0 projects. Hope that helps. Just replace the parts that start with YOUR_ with their corresponding info, and the connection object (once you reference ODP.NET) is `OracleConnection(connection_string)`.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the question: if you don't know the exact data that you need to complete a connection string (user id, password, host), search the computer for a file called "tnsnames.ora". That will hold all of the data you need - except the password.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ODP.NET use the following connection string

```
     string _ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = " + _host + ")(PORT = " + _port + "))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = " + _database + ")));Password=" + _password + ";User ID=" + _user;
```

If the connection works from sql developer, Right click on the connection name it will open the window as below

[image]

Replace _host with Hostname vale, _port with Port value, _database with SID, _user with Username and _password with Password values from sql properties box in the above c# connection string.